# Rearranging entries of rows in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to transform transform a numpy array A into B without using a loop.

```
A=np.array([[1,2,3],
            [1,3,0],
            [2,0,0]])

B=np.array([[1,2,3],
            [1,0,3],
            [0,2,0]])
```

So in each row, I want to reorder the entries using their value as the index.  (i.e. in row 2, `[1,3,0]`, 1 is the first entry, 3 is the third entry, and the 0 would fill in as the 2nd entry to make it `[1,0,3]`.

I can do this for a single row so I could loop through the array, but I wanted to see if there was a way to do this without a loop.  I know looping won't make a difference on small arrays like this, but I fear looping will create a bottleneck when doing this on large arrays (1m,1m).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, +1.

```
In [28]:

import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1,2,3],
            [1,3,0],
            [2,0,0]])
In [29]:

B=np.zeros(A.shape, 'int64')+np.arange(1, A.shape[0]+1)
In [30]:

np.where(np.asarray(map(np.in1d, B, A)), B, 0)
Out[30]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 3],
       [0, 2, 0]])
In [31]:

%timeit np.where(np.asarray(map(np.in1d, B, A)), B, 0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 156 µs per loop
```

Comment: Awesome answer!  This was exactly what I was looking for. I was stuck because I didn't know how to use np.in1d on a multidimensional array.  Why does map() break out each row into a separate array?

Comment: `map` is doing `np.in1d(B[0], A[0])`, `np.in1d(B[1], A[1])`, `np.in1d(B[2], A[2])`, ....... That does the trick, ;P.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach to get the same thing. Will probably be faster for large arrays:

```
>>> mask = A != 0
>>> rows, cols = A.shape
>>> idx = (A - 1 + (np.arange(rows)*cols)[:, None])[mask]
>>> B = np.zeros_like(A)
>>> B.ravel()[idx] = A[mask]
>>> B
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 3],
       [0, 2, 0]])
```

It converts the non-zero entries of `A` into indices in a flattened array, then uses those indices to copy the non-zero entries of `A` into their right positions in a flattened view of `B`.